# jQuery - getting prior value from within setInterval

Tags: jquery, datetime, setinterval

I want to do something (currently just testing by writing to the `console.log`) within a `setInterval` inside a web page.  When the interval cycles, I would like to pass in the **previous** value of the interval.  I am currently trying to do the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var lastTime, shiftTime = new Date();
    var myTimeString;
    var lastTimeString;
    myTimeString =  ('00' + (shiftTime.getHours())).slice(-2) +":"+('00' + (shiftTime.getMinutes())).slice(-2) + ":"+ ('00' + (shiftTime.getSeconds())).slice(-2) + "."+ ('000' + (shiftTime.getMilliseconds())).slice(-3);
    newInterval = myTimeString;
    lastTime  = lastTime - 300000;
    lastTimeString =  ('00' + (lastTime.getHours())).slice(-2) +":"+('00' + (lastTime.getMinutes())).slice(-2) + ":"+ ('00' + (lastTime.getSeconds())).slice(-2) + "."+ ('000' + (lastTime.getMilliseconds())).slice(-3);
    lastInterval = lastTimeString;
    console.log("lastInterval = " + lastInterval + "   thisInterval = " + newInterval);
    }, 300000);
```

The above is currently saying that `lastTime.getHours() is not a function`.

How do you get the last interval value (I would eventually need date & time both) from within the `setInterval` function?

Is there a better way to do this than how I'm approaching it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, be sure to initialize lastTime :

```
var lastTime = new Date(), shiftTime = new Date();
```

Then change

```
lastTime  = lastTime - 300000;
```

to

```
lastTime  = new Date(lastTime - 300000);
```

so that you get a `Date` object after having removed the `300000` ms.

Answer (score 4):

Any variables that you need to perpetuate between intervals should be declared outside of the interval function so they aren't killed by scope. e.g.

```
var valueToKeep;
setInterval(function(){
      var tempValue;
      // do something
      valueTokeep - tempValue;
}, 1000);
```

And @dystroy is correct; if you want to use the date methods, it's best you build a date object:

```
var foo = 123456;
var bar = new Date(ms), // gives you date object
    baz = foo - 86400; // just gives you a number
```